# Add html after or before an element using javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add html immediately after the li or immediately before the href in the following HTML:

```html
<li class="current-cat cat-parent" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenu" href="#childcats" id="parent-sidebar">
  <a href="http://www.mydomain/">Visit</a>
</li>
```

This is what I need to achieve:

```html
<li class="current-cat cat-parent" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenu" href="#childcats" id="parent-sidebar">
  <i class="fa"></i>
  <a href="http://www.mydomain/">Visit</a>
</li>
```

I tried this but it makes it part of the `a` and doesn't work:

```
jQuery('li.cat-parent a').prepend('<i class="fa"></i>');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML structure you're looking to create you need to append to the `a`, not the `li`:

```
jQuery('li.cat-parent').prepend('<i class="fa"></i>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`prepend()` adds the new element inside and at the start of the target element.

`before()` will add it as a sibling, that is the one you should use here.

Here are some reference links:

https://api.jquery.com/before/

https://api.jquery.com/after/

https://api.jquery.com/prepend/

https://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your selector to the `.cat-parent` element since that's the one you're adding to.
Also make sure the `i` element has the font awesome class correct to properly show the icon.

`jQuery('li.cat-parent').prepend('<i class="fa fa-">test</i>');`

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 solutions to solve this question. 2 of them are in vanilla js. Here are 4 of them:

## Insert in parent as first element (jQuery)

> **prependTo()**
>
> Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the beginning of the target.
>
> More info: [jQuery API Docs - prependTo()](https://api.jquery.com/prependto/)

```js
const setup = () => {

    /**
    Insert in parent as first element
  */

    //jquery
  const $catParent = $('.cat-parent');
  $('<i class="fa"></i>').prependTo($catParent);

}

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="current-cat cat-parent" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenu" href="#childcats" id="parent-sidebar">
  <a href="http://www.mydomain/">Visit</a>
</li>
```

## Insert in parent as first element (Vanilla JS)

> The **insertAdjacentHTML()** method of the Element interface parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position.
>
> `'afterbegin'`: Just inside the ´element`, before its first child.
>
> More info: [MDN Web Docs - insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
const setup = () => {

    /**
    Insert in parent as first element
  */

    //vanilla js
    const catParent = document.querySelector('.cat-parent');
  catParent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<i class="fa"></i>');

}

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<li class="current-cat cat-parent" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenu" href="#childcats" id="parent-sidebar">
  <a href="http://www.mydomain/">Visit</a>
</li>
```

## Insert before link (jQuery)

> **insertBefore()**
>
> Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.
>
> More info: [jQuery API Docs - insertBefore()](https://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

```js
const setup = () => {

    /**
    Insert before link
  */
  
  //jquery
  const $catParentLink = $('.cat-parent > a');
  $('<i class="fa"></i>').insertBefore($catParentLink);

}

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="current-cat cat-parent" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenu" href="#childcats" id="parent-sidebar">
  <a href="http://www.mydomain/">Visit</a>
</li>
```

## Insert before link (Vanilla JS)

> The **insertAdjacentHTML()** method of the Element interface parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position.
>
> `'beforebegin'`: Before the `element` itself.
>
> More info: [MDN Web Docs - insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
const setup = () => {

    /**
    Insert before link
  */
  
  //vanilla js
  const catParentLink = document.querySelector('.cat-parent > a');
  catParentLink.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<i class="fa"></i>');

}

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<li class="current-cat cat-parent" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseMenu" href="#childcats" id="parent-sidebar">
  <a href="http://www.mydomain/">Visit</a>
</li>
```